# php-mysql email contact importer

Tags: php, mysql

Dose anyone know how to get email address book for supplied email address and show or save them in a table. or any Open Source Package that provide this type of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at OpenInviter http://openinviter.com/ should helps

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to "get an address book" for any arbitrary email address - the existence of an email address doesn't even imply the existence of an address book in the first place; nor would there be any specific way to access it even if there were such that happened to be associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you **meant** to import from **Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail, AOL** then:

**[Have a look at this open-source project.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/contactgrabber/)**

Comment: @Laykes: yeah it is but was maintained in the project, not sure now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-addressbook/
You are however required to integrate it even against your system yourself, if you would like it.

Comment: The link is good, but that is not what i'm needed, i got OpenInviter http://openinviter.com/